# Meteor where to define my collection?

Tags: meteor

I have a pretty simple app structure that contain those libs

`server` - contain some configuration for routing and ENV

`client` - contain templates (`<template name=".*"></template>`) & JS File for every template

`collections`

now inside collections i have file called "Albums.js" and has a pretty simple content

`var Albums = new Meteor.Collection("Albums");`

now inside my client folder i'm trying to access to this variable `Albums` and i'm get undefined error.

my target is to take data from `form` and pass it to `collection.insert`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use var unless you want it private to that file.

> Albums = new Meteor.Collection("Albums");

Comment: What determines the order of the collections? I have them all global and inside the schema of collection x has a reference to an object inside the schema of collection y, but when i try to access it, it says `Collection y is not defined`. What can i do?

Answer (score 5):

another way to define global variables is to create new file, e.g. `collections.js` and put it directly into Your app root folder (not into any subfolder!)

In this file You can define global variable/collection (without `var` keyword)

Comment: Actually, you might want to put it in your `lib` folder to make sure it is loaded before most of the other scripts.

Answer (score 4):

Variables defined with `var` keyword are local to the file they're defined in. If you want a global variable, shared across files, you need to define it without the `var` keyword.

It looks like it's not in the doc, but it's in the https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md file (for version 0.6.0):

> Variables declared with var at the outermost level of a JavaScript source file are now private to that file. Remove the var to share a value between files.

Basically, each JS file is wrapped in the `(function(){ ... })();` pattern to provide this encapsulation.